# Tailwindcss typography: custom h3::before in a ordered list

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I customized the `h3` like this:

```
h3: {
    color: theme('colors.red.500'),
    fontFamily: `${theme('fontFamily.mono')}`,
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: '1rem',
},
```

Now I got an `ol` like this:

```
<li>
<h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
  </li>
  <li>diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
  </li>
  <li>et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
  </li>
</ol>
</li>
```

Now this is happening:

[image]

As you can see, the color of `h3::before` is not being adjusted to `colors.red.500`;

If I now add

```
'ol > li::before': {
    content: 'counter(list-item, var(--list-counter-style, decimal)) "."',
    position: 'absolute',
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontSize: '0.875rem',
    color: theme('colors.red.500'),
},
```

this is happening:

[image]

I just want the `1.` before `Lorem ipsum` to be red, too and the other ones not to be red ;-)

Comment: Could you add the part where you styled the `1.` to your `h3::before` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using classes, this might not be very reusable, but here's an example that you could in tailwind as well:

```css
h3 {
  color: red;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: custom-counter;
}

ol > li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: custom-counter;
}

ol > li > h3::before {
  content: counter(custom-counter) ". ";
  display: inline;
}

ol ol > li::before {
  content: counter(custom-counter) ". ";
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
      </li>
      <li>diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      </li>
      <li>et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
      </li>
      <li>diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      </li>
      <li>et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```